Compute: $\int \frac{\cos^2(x)+1}{\cos(x)\sqrt{\cos(x)}} dx$
Is there an actual "humane" way to evaluate this integral?
I thought about simplifying it and using semi-IBP(IBP on one term of the integrand) , however, that didn't work out because of its form: $$\int \sqrt{\cos(x)}+\frac{1}{\cos(x)\sqrt{\cos(x)}}dx$$
The answer is $\frac{2\sin(x)}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}}+C$. However, it's not very intuitive to obtain this answer when doing the reverse of this derivative.

What is semi-IBP? IBP on one term of the integrand?

@MathGuy Yep!!!

Then, your approach is indeed feasible.

Interestingly, WA can't do this without the hypergeometric function.

Substitute $t=\cos x$
\begin{align}
&\int \frac{\cos^2x+1}{\cos x\sqrt{\cos x}} dx\\
=& -\int\frac{1+t^2}{t\sqrt{t-t^3}}dt=-\int \frac {\frac1{t^2}+1}{\sqrt{\frac1t-t}}dt=\int \frac {d(\frac1t-t)}{\sqrt{\frac1t-t}}
\end{align}

Oh that's insane!! That surprisingly turned out nicely!!

Without integration
You can even guess the result
$$I=\int \frac{\cos^2(x)+1}{\cos(x)\sqrt{\cos(x)}}\, dx$$
$$x=2\tan^{-1}(t) \quad \implies \quad I=\int \frac{4
   \left(t^4+1\right)}{\left(1-t^4\right)^{3/2}}\,dt$$ Assume (because of the denominator) that
$$I=\frac {P(t)}{\left(1-t^4\right)^{1/2}}$$ So
$$4\left(t^4+1\right)=-\left(t^4-1\right) P'(t)+2 t^3 P(t)$$ So, $P(t)$ is a polynomial of degree $1$.
Let $P(t)=a+b t$ and replace
$$4t^4+4=b t^4+2 a t^3+b \quad \implies \quad a=0\quad \text{and}\quad b=4$$
So
$$I=\frac {4t}{\left(1-t^4\right)^{1/2}}$$
Replace $t$ by $\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ to get
$$I=2 \sin (x) \sqrt{\sec (x)}$$

@ClaudeLeibovivi recommend some books for me that’ll help difficult integration

Notice that:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\cos^2(x)+1}{\cos(x)\sqrt{\cos(x)}}&=\frac{\cos^2(x)+\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)}{\cos(x)\sqrt{\cos(x)}} \\
&=\frac{2\cos(x)\sqrt{\cos(x)}+\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}}}{\cos(x)}
\end{align*}
This looks a lot like the quotient rule for differentiation of $\frac{u}{v}$ with $u=2\sin(x)$ and $v=\sqrt{\cos(x)}$. So, you're really just computing the following integral
$$\int\frac{d}{dx}\frac{2\sin(x)}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}}dx$$

Divide numerator and denominator by $\cos^2(x)$
$$ \int \frac{1+\sec^2(x)}{\sqrt{\sec(x)}}dx = \int \sqrt{\cos(x)} + \frac{\sec^2(x)}{\sqrt{\sec(x)}}dx$$
which now suggests multiplying numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{\sin(x)}$ to get a $\sqrt{\tan(x)}$ in the denominator
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{\sin(x)\cos(x)}}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}+\sqrt{\sin(x)}\frac{\sec^2(x)}{\sqrt{\tan(x)}}dx = \int\frac{\cos(x)\sqrt{\tan(x)}}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}+\sqrt{\sin(x)}\frac{\sec^2(x)}{\sqrt{\tan(x)}}dx$$
which we now recognize as product rule
$$= 2\sqrt{\sin(x)\tan(x)}+C$$

Woah 0o0, I would've never seen that, but someone would definitely run into this route naturally by accident and then notice a reverse product rule!!

The second term you wrote can be prepared for IBP as follows:
$$\begin{align}\int\sqrt{\cos x}+\sec^\frac32x\mathrm dx&=\int\sqrt{\cos x}\mathrm dx+\int\sqrt{\cos x}\mathrm d(\tan x)\\&=\int\sqrt{\cos x}\mathrm dx+\tan x\sqrt{\cos x}+\int\tan x\frac{\sin x}{2\sqrt{\cos x}}\mathrm dx\\&=\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{\cos x}}+\frac12\int\sec^\frac32x+\sqrt{\cos x}\mathrm dx\end{align}$$
$$\therefore\boxed{\int\sqrt{\cos x}+\sec^\frac32x\mathrm dx=\frac{2\sin x}{\sqrt{\cos x}}+C}$$
